# Rewriting this code with jQuery map function

Tags: jquery, dictionary

I am creating an array to store in cookie using jquery.cookies.js
Below is the way I am storing and accessing values from an array

```
var th = $(this);
var TempRecord = []; // Defining an Array to store all attributes 
var Q = th.find('Name').first().text();
var NR = th.attr('NotReq');
var FieldWidth = th.attr('FWidth');
```

And Pushing elements into an array like this

```
if(th.attr('FieldWidth'))
{
    TempRecord.push("Field Width");
    TempRecord.push(FieldWidth);
}
```

Then joining the array as below to store in an array as a string

```
var temp = TempRecord.join('splitter'); Then storing into cookie...

// Like the above I am storing all the other attribute values
```

And accessing them like below

```
var rec = temp.split('splitter');
for(var i=0;i<rec-1;i=i+2)
{
   var x = rec[i];
   var y = rec[i+1];
}
```

Please suggest me a way improve the above code. And also please remember that I am gonna store this in cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use JSON for serialising your data, something like:

```
var tempRecord = [];
if (th.attr("FieldWidth")) {
    tempRecord.push({
        fieldWidth: _fieldWidth
    });
}

var temp = JSON.stringify(tempRecord);
```

And then to get it out again:

```
var rec = JSON.parse(valueFromCookie);
```

In order to ensure cross-browser compatibility for `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` you would need to include [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js).

Comment: How to access from the cookie or the values from the DOM?